# Unable to deserialize object as its class, but only as its parent's

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I have a server receiving data that was serialized using boost serialization text_archive. The arriving data can be one of the following `MB_BPRequest` or `MB_BPResponse`, both of which extend `MB_BPMessage`.

So I have this code:

```
request_callback(MB_BPRequest);
response_callback(MB_BPResponse);

try {
  MB_BPRequest req;
  archive >> req;
  request_callback_(req);
}
catch (std::exception& e) {
  MB_BPResponse resp;
  archive >> resp;
  response_callback_(resp);
}
```

and the strange thing is that it will only deserialize the archive if i use the base class:

```
  MB_BPMessage req;
  archive >> req;
  request_callback_(/*cast somehow*/req);
```

else it throws an "Input stream error".

The problem with this is that I cannot cast `MB_BPMessage` to either `MB_BPRequest` or `MB_BPResponse` because the compiler throws errors.

I'm interested in hearing other approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only (de)serialize polymorphic types through a pointer. See

- docs http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers

In particular if you really *must* serialize these through a reference, you'll have to deal with ownership semantics manually:

- docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#references

> We address these questions by serializing references as though they were pointers.

Comment: The problem with this is that `MB_BPRequest` and `MB_BPResponse` are not actually polymorphic - they just share some of the functionality with their base class `MB_BPMessage`, but there are no virtual methods.

Comment: @Mak In that case, why do you expect to be able to extract a different type (`MB_BPMessage`) than was serialized? That's just an error. You may want to use `boost::variant<MB_BPRequest, MB_BPResponse>` instead - as long as you _serialize the same type as you deserialize_

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough. When I serialize `MB_BPRequest` I can only deserialize it as a `MB_BPMessage` else I get an exception.
I will look int boost::variant<>. Thank you

Comment: I think my comment was spot on. You just don't show the serializing code, but I can bet that it serializes a `MB_BPMessage`... If not, please add the relevant code to the question ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: Here's a comprehensive example that shows what likely can have gone wrong: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e173994c77540b5e)**. Note also how incompatible deserializations might not even raise an error (here it silently returns wrong results). The [***live-stream*** recording](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/comparison-deserializing-derived-messages/) is still available

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort explaining so thoroughly. Some things are way clearer now. It turns out in the end I was casting `MB_BPRequest` and `MB_BPResponse` to `MB_BPMessage`. But watching your live stream I figured out I should probably stick to templates or overloading for this one.